# Adding ChildViewControllers Using Storyboard Not Working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Storyboard which is shown below in the screenshot:

[image]

From my HomeController I segue to ContainerViewController using the code below. For some reason the childControllers is always nil.

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
            fatalError("No row selected")
        }

        let place = self.places[indexPath.row]

        let containerViewController = segue.destination as! ContainerViewController

        containerViewController.childViewControllers // THIS IS NIL WHY!!!
```

Comment: I don't think they have loaded when this func is called. They would be loaded after `viewDidLoad` in your container controller.

Comment: @john doe, where you add the children viewcontroller?